# Access Elements file on Feature Activated in Sandboxed solution

Tags: sandbox-solution, sharepoint-server

I need to access an Element file in feature activated event in sandboxed solution. How do I do it. `properties.Feature.RootDirectory` is not present in sandboxed solution. anyway to go around to access Element file - 'ElementsFile1.xml' present in module - 'Feature1Module'? 
Here is the code snippet I am trying

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        using (SPSite site = ((SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent).Site)
        { 
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
            xmlDoc.Load(properties.Feature.RootDirectory + @"'Feature1Module'/'ElementsFile1.xml"); 
            foreach (XmlElement fieldNode in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) 
            {
              site.RootWeb.Fields.AddFieldAsXmlfieldNode.OuterXml);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I acheived it through `Web.GetFile()` as follows

`public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        using (SPSite site = ((SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent).Site)
        { 
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
            SPFile file = site.RootWeb.GetFile("Feature1Module/ElementsFile1.xml");
            byte[] content = file.OpenBinary();
            Stream strm = new MemoryStream(content);
            xmlDoc.Load(strm); 
            foreach (XmlElement fieldNode in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) 
            {
              site.RootWeb.Fields.AddFieldAsXmlfieldNode.OuterXml);
            }
        }
    }`